# Implementing C++ code into ROS using roscpp

Tags: c++, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I write a program in C++, is there a way for ROS to recognize it and run the code through roscpp? I am writing a C++ program to recognize a sensor (connected via USB), read in the data, track the data, etc. Will roscpp allow me to run that C++ program through ROS? (I will be using diamondback and the TurtleBot).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12842/implementing-c++-code-into-ros-using-roscpp/) by [scheithauer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1725/scheithauer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should have a look at the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Tutorials) for roscpp. They will show you how to do what you're trying to do.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6